# Are there any published post-apocalypse style adventures?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, post-apocalyptic

I am looking at a homebrew campaign in a post-apocalypse world and looking for inspiration on the kind of scenario's that might occur.

Are there any officially published adventures for any edition, set in any world, that follow an apocalyptic event?

Comment: I am not sure how this is shopping or asking for recommendations, I am asking about published material on a specific theme by a certain publisher. Sounds more like a well defined closed list to me, or is the 'any other system' sidenote the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest "or any other system" removal, as I can see how that got the shopping response.  I almost noted that when I encountered the question, but once you responded to my comment I felt like you were keeping it D&D specific due to the tag.  My guess (was I wrong?)  If you are asking for any system at all, yeah, that would make it more like a game rec question.

Comment: “Recommend me adventures of type X for me to read” has [all the problems of a shopping recommendation question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/321) because it is a shopping recommendation question. The “but it’s a short list” negates the Too Broad reason to close list questions, but shopping questions are off topic for their own reasons, not for being list questions or for being Too Broad. No kind of shopping question is on topic.

Comment: Also, it’s easily arguable it’s a very *long* list, as a google search for “D&D post apocalypse” gets pages and pages of adventures and settings.

Comment: Yeah, this is either a shopping recommendation or an unbounded list.  Sorry, we don't do these here on RPG.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [AD&D 2e / D&D 4e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Sun) Dark Sun: a post apocalyptic setting

A core premise of the *Dark Sun* setting was that an apocalypse happened and as a result magic profoundly changed. Gods / deities and their connections to PCs were more or less removed, clerics draw from elemental planes rather than divine power, and *Dark Sun* was as much a survival test as anything else.  The state of Athas, as a world, is degraded due to both technological and magical effects in the past.  Arcane magic tends to be either of a "preserver" or "defiler" category.

> Dark Sun differs further in that the game has no deities, arcane magic is reviled for causing the planet's current ecological fragility, and psionics are extremely common.

There are a list of adventures/modules at the link in the title.

It was inspired by the "dying earth" genre of SF/Swords and Sorcery short stories and novels.

> Dark Sun is an original Dungeons & Dragons (D&D) campaign setting set
> in the fictional, post-apocalyptic desert world of Athas. Dark Sun
> featured an innovative metaplot, influential art work, dark themes,
> and a genre-bending take on traditional fantasy role-playing. The
> product line began with the original Dark Sun Boxed Set released for
> D&D's 2nd edition in 1991, originally ran until 1996, and was one
> of TSR's most successful releases.

Athas is not the warm and cuddly Forgotten Realms, and it's not even the World of Greyhawk.  It's just dangerous.

How available Dark Sun materials are may depend on where you are and what you are willing to spend, but I saw some at DriveThruRPG.  There were a number of novels published for the Dark Sun setting that you may be able to pick up for cheap at a second hand book store.  (I found them easy reading while I was at sea, but as with any TSR-published novels, the quality varied).

You can also find Dark Sun materials from 4th edition, but I have no experience with that edition.

---

Notes:
<sub>You may find it of interest that Jack Vance, whose magical system Gary Gygax adapted for the original game, wrote a number of Dying Earth stories that are on the reading list of inspiration for D&D).</sub>

<sub>I only got to play this for a little while, now and again, due to game groups breaking up and me giving up the hobby for a while.  Of all the settings that D&D had before, this is the one I am hoping WoTC will resurrect into a D&D 5e form.  The devs are still trying to get the psionics thing to work (there have been 3 UAs so far) and it will or won't pan out.   (Sorry, Mr Baker, Eberron is nice, but Dark Sun is IMO better in the sense of "less is more.")</sub>